# /etc/resolver forward lookup zones are not being included in name resolution

Tags: macos, networking, dns, osx-mountain-lion

I'm trying to set up HypeDNS on Mac OS X 10.8.4 (Mountain Lion). It allows me to send all .hype domain names to another DNS address for lookup and resolution. I've been instructed to add the file `/etc/resolver/hype` to the system, with contents `nameserver <IPv6AddressOfServer>` (HypeDNS runs on the Hyperboria network and atop `cjdns`, which is a virtual meshnet that only accepts IPv6, so IPv4 is not something I'm worrying about). So I placed the `/etc/resolver/hype` in its rightful place, with contents as specified above. I've restarted the computer and ensured that `cjdns` is operational (Little Snitch reports that there are 15 connections with the `cjdns` program at any time, and the ambient data sent on my usage meter proves that). Then, I run `ping6 nodeinfo.hype` (nodeinfo.hype is an address that should always be up) and the prompt freezes up for as long as one minute, and then it outputs:

> `ping6: getaddrinfo -- nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

Similarly, I have tried to resolve to other websites on the Hyperboria network that utilize HypeDNS, and I've been unable to reach them.

**Resources you might find useful for answering this:**

- [The Instructions I followed](https://wiki.projectmeshnet.org/HypeDNS#On_OSX)
- Article/forum that suggests that [`/etc/resolver` might be broken on Lion and above](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3339686)
- [How `/etc/resolver` is supposed to work on Mac](http://www.dforge.net/2013/01/30/osx-domain-specific-dns-servers-etcresolver/)

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the one above the only modification you made? I mean, the introduction of /etc/resolver/hype?

Comment: Yes, this is the only change I made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so everyone knows, I fixed the issue. The problem was not the `/etc/resolver` forward lookup zones, but rather the automatic IPv6 management system on OS X. Go to System Preferences > Network > Wi-Fi > Advanced > TCP/IP > Configure IPv6 > Manually.

Then, set `::` as the IPv6 address and `64` as the prefix length. Leave the Router field blank. Then `cjdns` should work.